# how to detect UIview lost focus or get focus in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, focus

I'm developing in a scroll view a page, where there is some youtube videos with YoutubeKit framework.

YoutubeKit is using UIView to show video. I would like to pause video when the UIView isn't in focus (not shown but user).

isfocused() is working but I would like to get "an event", to automatically react when the focus is lost.

i understood I need to create a custom UIview class to override canBecomeFocused

here is the code of the custom class I've created

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class focusableUIview: UIView {
    override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withcoordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    print("focus")
}
}
```

I've also updated story board on changing the class of the UIView i want to detect focus change.

what I'm questioning, what I need to do in the UIviewcontroller class, I've noticed canBecomeFocused is never called...

I'm a bit lost. many thanks for your help

Comment: What you meant by **focus** here??

Comment: hello, by focus I mean something is appeared on user's screen. A video can still play even if not viewed on the smartphone. I want to avoid it.

Comment: you can use [contains(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454186-contains). It will check whther your videoView inside mainView or not.

Comment: @victor if you share some code, I believe that it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @victor you can implement delegate that would provide this `UIView` function to `UIViewController` https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Make your view focusable

```
override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then override this function to get update on focus

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

}
```

Comment: I've created a custom class

Comment: @victor yes, you need to create your custom class inheriting `UIView`. Then, override this functions.

Comment: I've update the original post with code I've extracted.

Comment: User is already doing this in the code they posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think focus-based UI system is for tvOS. UIKit can be used to develop apps for Apple TV. But focus has no effect on iOS.

> A UI element is in focus when the user highlights an item, but has not selected an item.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH12-SW1